# Trigger event on completion of video in videocard - MS Bot Framework

Tags: azure-bot-service, web-chat

Greetings of the day!
I have a situation for chat bot. I have a video which i am showing to user through a video card. Is there a way to add a piece of script in botchat.js so that I can trigger an event like posting a data to a api when the video will be completly played.

Thanks in advance.